# Xaf new project has yellow triangles

Tags: c#, xaf

I upgraded to the latest version 21.2.6.
If I create a new project, the references show as 21.2 in the .csproj file
However the assemblies all display with yellow triangles.
The same is true if I open a sources project.

[image: yellow triangles]

I can fix the issue by editing the .csproj and changing 21.2 to 21.2.6

However, is there a way to fix this without editing the .csproj?

[Update]

The build error on a new project is

> Warning   NU1603  DXApplication47.Module depends on DevExpress.ExpressApp
> (>= 21.2.0) but DevExpress.ExpressApp 21.2.0 was not found. An
> approximate best match of DevExpress.ExpressApp 21.2.3 was
> resolved. DXApplication47.Module  C:\Users\kirst\source\repos\DXApplication47\DXApplication47.Module\DXApplication47.Module.csproj    1

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It turned out that I had some local package sources for Dev Express.
I thought they would not be used because they were unchecked in the sources dialog ( VS2022->Tools->Optons->NuGet Package Manager->Package Sources )
When I deleted them the problem was resolved.

Comment: I was getting this error again today on creating a new winforms project after upgrading to 21.2.8.  i had the local package source unchecked because I thought Nuget might be enough.  The problem went away when I checked the package source containing the correct local nuget files.